# Database execution results and mybatis execution results are inconsistent

Tags: mysql, mybatis, spring-mybatis

use:

```
1.mysql 5.6.36
2.mybatis 3.4.5
```

in the database,i exceute the four sql,here the logs:

```
SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@54b0f2cd] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql://xxxx/xxxx, UserName=xxxx@xxxx, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver] will not be managed by Spring
==>  Preparing: select IFNULL(count(*),0) from goods_info 
==> Parameters: 
<==    Columns: IFNULL(count(*),0)
<==        Row: 149
<==      Total: 1
Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@54b0f2cd]
Creating a new SqlSession
SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@25b99cbf] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql://xxxx/xxxx, UserName=xxxx@xxxx, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver] will not be managed by Spring
==>  Preparing: select sum(browsed_times) from goods_info 
==> Parameters: 
<==    Columns: sum(browsed_times)
<==        Row: 10128
<==      Total: 1
Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@25b99cbf]
Creating a new SqlSession
SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@5d271b1a] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql://xxxx/xxxx, UserName=xxxx@xxxx, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver] will not be managed by Spring
==>  Preparing: select IFNULL(count(*),0) from user 
==> Parameters: 
<==    Columns: IFNULL(count(*),0)
<==        Row: 694
<==      Total: 1
Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@5d271b1a]
Creating a new SqlSession
SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@20bbe729] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql://xxxx/xxxxx, UserName=xxxx@xxxx, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver] will not be managed by Spring
==>  Preparing: select IFNULL(sum(total_price),0) from order_build where order_status = '已支付' 
==> Parameters: 
<==    Columns: IFNULL(sum(total_price),0)
<==        Row: 0.00
<==      Total: 1
```

and now i find the first three are consistent with database,but the last one is error.when i excute it in the database ,i can get the correct result.

here is my mapper.xml:

```
<select id="getTotalMoney" resultType="String">
    select IFNULL(sum(total_price),0)
    from order_build
    where order_status =
    '已支付'
</select>
```

in database ,i get this result:

[image]

i am upset.i don`t know why.

Answer (score 0):

Reslove.
i specify the Encoding with utf8.